# How do I create a multi-value function that applies to a class in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming

I have created a class and am attempting to create a function that will, in essence, act as a binary operator between two objects of that class. The function I was trying to create is called 'combine'.

I know I could create the function outside of the class, but I want it to be associated with the class.

Background (not really necessary for answering the question) - the class is modelling the S4 mathematical group and is some practice with objects and classes for me. My next function was to be to simplify an element into it's simplest expression in cycles, which I am confident that I could do, but I would rather get this one sorted first.

When I create a function with one argument, it runs fine - as demonstrated in the code below, with the function 'cycletype', which works as expected.

```
class s4:

    # Define an element of s4, elementlist is a nested list, which is a list of the cycles composing the element.

    def __init__(self, elementlist):
        self.elementlist = elementlist

    # One simple function is to ascertain the cycletype of the element.

    def cycletype(self):
        cycles = []
        for i in self.elementlist:
            cycles.append(len(i))
        return cycles

    # Combining two elements using the group operation is the first function to define.

    def combine(first, second):
        for i in second:
            first.append(i)
        return first

double = s4([[1,2],[3,4]])
triple = s4([[1,2,3]])

print(combine(double,triple))
```

I was expecting [[1,2],[3,4],[1,2,3]] to be printed, however, it showed a NameError, not recognising combine.

Comment: `s4.combine`? You made the choice to put the function in the class, so you have to access it that way too

Comment: `combine` is declared under `s4` so this is why you get the err

Comment: Shouldn't `combine` be returning a *new* instance anyway, rather than modifying the first on in-place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be creating a *new* instance from the lists wrapped by the two arguments:

```
class S4:

    # Define an element of S4, elementlist is a nested list, which is a list of the cycles composing the element.

    def __init__(self, elementlist):
        self.elementlist = elementlist

    # One simple function is to ascertain the cycletype of the element.

    def cycletype(self):
        cycles = []
        for i in self.elementlist:
            cycles.append(len(i))
        return cycles

    # Combining two elements using the group operation is the first function to define.

    def combine(self, first, second):
        return S4(first.element_list + second.element_list)
```

It also appears that you could simply define `__add__` instead of `combine`,

```
# Simplified implementation, no error checking
def __add__(self, second):
    return S4(self.element_list + second.element_list)
```

allowing you to write

```
print(double + triple)
```

instead of

```
print(combine(double, triple))
```

Answer (score 0):

There's two problems with the code

- putting the function *inside* the class means that it's a method. So, you have to access it using the object `s4.combine(s1)`, not just `combine(...)`. Otherwise, it would be a function, not a method.
- After you change that: you can't write `for i in second`, because instances of your class are not iterable. You have to implement `__iter__` to be able to use that syntax

Answer (score 0):

This is because the combine function isn't present in the global scope ( I hope that's what its called, I mess up names real bad).

You can only call functions present in the global scope, in the case of classes, you need objects to call these functions as these functions are part of those specific classes and not the global scope in general.

Hope this helped

Comment: Yes, "global scope" is correct. The rest of the answer, as I understand it, is not. https://pastebin.com/6BSDkni0

Comment: Hi @roganjosh, I too am starting up but I guess what you are trying to say is that we can access the function by directly using the class name. But I have always believed the interpreter creates some sort a pseudo object and then calls it. Is that wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There's a scope problem, you defined combine within the s4 class, so you should call it from a instance of s4. Anyways, here's is how I would do it.

```
class s4:

    # Define an element of s4, elementlist is a nested list, which is a list of the cycles composing the element.
    def __init__(self, elementlist):
        self.elementlist = elementlist

    # One simple function is to ascertain the cycletype of the element.

    def cycletype(self):
        cycles = []
        for i in self.elementlist:
            cycles.append(len(i))
        return cycles

    # Combining two elements using the group operation is the first function to define.

    def combine(self, second):
      #Here I changed first to self, first would be the s4 class that calls the function, in this example double and second would be the one that you want to combine
        first = self.elementlist
        for i in second.elementlist:
            first.append(i)
        return first

double = s4([[1,2],[3,4]])
triple = s4([[1,2,3]])
##As double() is defined within the s4 class, you can only call it from an instance of s4 (in this case you could use doble.combine() or triple.combine())
print(double.combine(triple))
```

Hope it helps.